# Synchronize excel file with SharePoint online list

Tags: list, client-object-model, excel

I want to synchronize data from excel file with SharePoint list on office 365.
I have already built a utility which uses client object model to achieve this but it is very slow as item count are in thousands.
Please explain if there is any other better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

[SharePoint List Synchronizer](http://www.softfluent.com/wsslists.htm%22) is working for me to restore automatically the two-way synchronization feature between Excel and SharePoint online lists. I found it very reliable and easy to use!

Answer (score 0):

Go through this link which shows you steps by step method

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/synchronize-a-sharepoint-list-with-a-spreadsheet-HA101964719.aspx (This link is broken)

New link (but for 2010):

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Synchronize-a-SharePoint-list-with-a-spreadsheet-program-d4337a01-2be4-43b5-bb42-28aefe64eafd

Comment: Please do not only provide links as answers, if the link breaks, your answer will be of little help to readers. Try to add the important bits from the link to you post